# What's wrong with using setter injection for an Android ViewModel vs Implementing and injecting a ViewModel.Factory?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I have been struggling with getting a Dagger singleton injected into an android component (Service) and a ViewModel.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47444843/cant-inject-same-instance-into-a-service-and-a-viewmodel) as a reference.
I have not found a good example of how to simply inject a field in a Service and a field in a ViewModel with the **same** object.  If there is a simple solution to that I would love to see it.

I found some questions, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270577/android-lifecycle-library-viewmodel-using-dagger-2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042989/kotlin-dagger-inject-map-for-viewmodel-factory), that have answers that go down a path of implementing ViewModel.Factory and then injecting dependencies into the constructor of a ViewModel subclass that has dependencies via the create method.

My question is. Are there any serious issues with just injecting the object in to the Activity (and the Service) and then using a setter to inject the object into the ViewModel after it has been retrieved?  For example.

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    @Inject lateinit var messageBus: MessageBus // "thing" I want in the ViewModel
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        AndroidInjection.inject(this)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // get the ViewModel
        val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java) 
        // inject the "thing" via a setter 
        viewModel.messageBus = messageBus 
    }
}
```

In the view `MainViewModel` class I could check to see if the value has been already be set, and only set it if it's null.

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    var messageBus: MessageBus? = null
    set(value) {
        if (field == null) {
            field = value
            // do initialization stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see it as a little hack, but not a harmful hack. I like the idea of providing the `ViewModelFactory` using dagger along with all dependencies necessary for it to function and then injecting that into the activity so you can pass it in to the `of(FragmentActivity activity, ViewModelProvider.Factory factory)` method. It avoids mutability on that property.